# Launch rails webrick server at startup

Tags: bash, startup, rails

I want webrick running at startup. So I execute this command in terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

Then added this line to the end of the file

```
@reboot /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin/ruby /home/myname/redmine-2.3.1/script/rails server webrick -e production
```

and restarted Ubuntu. However, the server still didn't start when my Ubuntu booted.

Any help on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is to add this two lines in crontab:

```
PATH = /home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin:$PATH
@reboot ruby script/rails server webrick -e production
```

Or, better, use [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/147044) to start webrick automatically on login.

Comment: Radeanu thanks for your answer but they both are not working for me. Any other idea?

Comment: @petwho Can you start it from terminal? If yes, how?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by starting it from terminal. However, I tried both on terminal and GUI approaches. For GUI approach (which you linked on your answer): I entered this line: "/home/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin/ruby /home/myname/redmine-2.3.1/script/rails server webrick -e production &" to "command" field (and event removed the ampersand character at the end of the command). They both not working. I also added "x" permission to all users to file under ~/.config/autostart/webrick and /etc/rc.local. I'm really getting hairy with this.